# Extending function from $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \to [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Can a continuous function on $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ be extended to a continuous function on $[0,1]$?

Comment: Try $f(x) = \frac{1}{x - 1/\pi}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f : \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=1$ if $x< \sqrt{2}/2$ and $f(x)=-1$ if $x> \sqrt{2}/2$.

**Remark:** In fact, every irrational number in $[0,1]$ can be used instead of $\sqrt{2}/2$.

Comment: Is this function $f$ continuous on $ℚ$? I don't exactly know what it means to be continuous on $ℚ$...

Comment: If $x<\sqrt{2}/2$, there exists $(a,b) \subset [0,\sqrt{2}/2]$ containing $x$; if $x>\sqrt{2}/2$, there exists $(a,b) \subset [\sqrt{2}/2,1]$ containing $x$. Therefore, $f$ is locally constant, and so continuous.

Comment: Hmm.. sounds like a strange definition of continuous to me. What if I would make a function that starts at $0$ and goes one up after the points $\frac 1 n + \frac 1 π , \frac 2 n + \frac 1 π , \frac 3 n + \frac 1 π$ etc. would such a function also be cont. on $ℚ$ ? I quess I didn't defined it well, but the idea is the same as with your function.

Comment: I didn't give a definition; $f: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ if for every interval $(a,b)$ containing $f(x)$, there exists an interval $(c,d)$ containing $x$ such that $f((c,d)) \subset (a,b)$.